# ccBezierConfig as a quadratic, not cubic.

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, bezier

So I'm trying to animate a sprite, and I just found the CCBezierBy/CCBezierTo methods, which are saving me a lot of trouble, but they only work as cubic functions.

HOw can I make them quadratics? (I need s-curves)

Having only 3 controlpoints limits severely what you can do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand Bezier curves here: S curves cannot be modeled by quadratic Beziers, they can only do curves with a single inflection point. Cubic curves can have two inflection points, so quadratic curves can only model curves that look like | or C, and cubic curves can model anything that looks like |, C or S

Cubic functions have a starting on-curve point, two control points, and an ending on-curve point, for a total of four control points; Quadratic functions have a starting on-curve point, one control point, and an ending on-curve point, for a total of three control points.

So what you want is a cubic curve, and that's exactly what the CCBezierBy/CCBezierTo methods offer. They let you specify a bezier curve as the two control points and end point, because you'll already have the starting point.